# PHP isset validation

Tags: php, validation, isset

Hi guys any idea why this piece of code always returns true weather form fields are empty or not?

```
//Validate input
if ((!isset($_POST['user']) && 'user' == '') && (!isset($_POST['message']) && 'message' == '' )) 
{ echo 'false'; } else { echo 'true'; }
```

Comment: You are missing `$_POST` . it should be `!isset($_POST['user']) && $_POST['user'] == '')`

Comment: Your tests makes no logic from where I see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((isset($_POST['user']) && $_POST['user'] != '') && (isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] != '')) { 
    echo 'true'; 
} else { 
    echo 'false'; 
}
```

Or simply

```
if (empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['message']))  { 
    echo 'false'; 
} else { 
    echo 'true'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'user' == ''
```

and

```
'message' == ''
```

are always false, so you get the else statement echoed... use $_POST['user'] and $_POST['message'] instead

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not using the conditions correctly. Try this instead:

```
if ((!isset($_POST['user']) && $_POST['user'] == '') && (!isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] == '' )) {
    echo 'false';
} else {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Not sure what you are trying to check though. Update your question with some more details if you want a better answer.

Comment: Thank you guys. You've helped me. It's solved thanks to you.
Cheers